# NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath removes file only once app terminates

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

So I am using the methods bellow to handle getting, deleting, and saving images for my app. When I call `removeImage` it succeeds and when I use `NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath` it says the file does not exist. However, when I call `getImage` it can still grab the image even though it has been deleted. When I quite the app and start it up again `getImage` works as expected until I use `removeImage`. I have also tried wrapping the `removeImage` call in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{})` and it still doesn't work.

My code:

```
class func removeImage(user:User){
    let context = getManagedObjectContext()
    context.performBlockAndWait({
        guard let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as [String]! where paths.count > 0 else{
            return
        }

        do{
            if let dirPath = paths[0] as String!{
                let path = "\(user.id)_\(user.name).png"
                let readPath = (dirPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(readPath)
            }
        }catch{
        }
    })
}

class func saveImage(user:User,image:UIImage){
    let path = "\(user.id)_\(user.name).png"
    guard let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as [String]! where paths.count > 0 else{
        return
    }
    if let dirPath = paths[0] as String!{
        let writePath = (dirPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
        UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!.writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true)
    }
}


class func getImage(user:User)->UIImage?{
    let path = "\(user.id)_\(user.name).png"
    guard let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as [String]! where paths.count > 0 else{
        return nil
    }
    if let dirPath = paths[0] as String!{
        let readPath = (dirPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
        return UIImage(named: readPath)
    }
    return nil
}
```

UPDATE/FIX! Changed code to this and it worked:

```
class func removeImage(user:User){
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    do{
        let directoryURL = try manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentationDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(user.id)_\(user.name).png", relativeToURL: directoryURL)
            try manager.removeItemAtURL(url)
        } else {
            let url = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(user.id)_\(user.name).png")
            try manager.removeItemAtURL(url)
        }
    }catch{

    }
}


class func saveImage(user:User,image:UIImage){
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    do{
        let directoryURL = try manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentationDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(user.id)_\(user.name).png", relativeToURL: directoryURL)
            UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!.writeToURL(url, atomically: true)
        } else {
            let url = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(user.id)_\(user.name).png")
            UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!.writeToURL(url, atomically: true)
        }
    }catch{

    }
}

class func getImage(user:User)->UIImage?{
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    do{
        let directoryURL = try manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentationDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(user.id)_\(user.name).png", relativeToURL: directoryURL)
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                return UIImage(data: data)
            }
        } else {
            let url = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(user.id)_\(user.name).png")
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                return UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }catch{

    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I would start it over using NSURL instead of casting to NSString to use paths.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out.

Comment: Still the same problem with NSURLs instead

Comment: Actually that solved it! Not sure why using NSURL would work and paths wouldn't though...